# I need help pulling info from a .txt file into a table in either access or excel

Tags: transaction, ms-access, import

So..  I've tried both Excel and Access to do what I need but I don't know the programs well enough to get them to do what I want, if it's even possible.

I have a hourly updating .txt file with multiple dozens of blocks of information in this format

Location: *LOCATION1*
Sublocation: Unit B
*Material1* - - - - (***vv.vv***)
*Material2* - - - - (***xx.xx***)
*Material3* - - - - (***yy.yy***)
*Material4* - - - - (***zz.zz***)

And I need to pull data from that file using the *LOCATION* and *Product 1-x* to update the applicable cells with the new numbers.

Current table is in this format, and NO I don't have any ability to alter the layout of the table to make importing data into it easier. (all values are different and go to different cells even though I used same letters for different examples) Some cells in the table currently have a value in them but need to be removed if that material value in the text file is blank.

-------*Loc1*---*Loc2*---*Loc3*---*Loc4* 
*Mat1*| ***vv.vv*** | ***yy.yy*** | ***xx.xx*** | - - - -
*Mat2*| ***xx.xx*** | - - - - | ***zz.zz*** | ***vv.vv***
*Mat3*| ***zz.zz*** | ***vv.vv*** | ***yy.yy*** | ***xx.xx***
*Mat4*| - - - - | ***zz.zz*** | ***xx.xx*** | ***zz.zz***
*Mat5*| ***xx.xx*** | ***xx.xx*** | ***zz.zz*** | ***vv.vv***

Any help you can give me would be appreciated. As it currently stands I must individually take each new number, find its relevant Location in the table, and update it manually. As my company adds more and more locations its becoming a more taxing and time consuming endeavor that I, and likely they, would love to be able to automate. As stated earlier I have tried the import wizard in Excel and Access but I lack sufficient skills with either to get them to do what was necessary. I look forward to your comments and questions if you have any.

Comment: did you try to follow the staps from m$ https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-link-to-data-in-a-text-file-d6973101-9547-4315-a8f8-02911b549306

Comment: Based on the semi-non-normalized format of your data in the text file, it may not be possible, or at least easy, to do a straight import with it. You may need to write your own application that can paras the file first and then connects to your database to save the data down to. This question may be better served being asked on [StackOverflow.com](https://www.StackOverflow.com) instead.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Of course I've gone through the support steps and all the help files looking for what I need but have been unsuccessful.  I was afraid someone would tell me that J.D. Thanks though for your unfortunate and likely very accurate assesment of the problem.

Comment: Welcome UmßraDivisio! Read [The Tour](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour) and earn your first badge!

Comment: Please use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table from your data and edit it into your question.

Comment: Try adapting [this code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-readCSV.html) to read a .CSV file character by character using Excel or MS Access